# EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/ashu/.vue-templates/webpack-simple/README.md

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, node.js, npm

I have installed nodejs and npm using nvm. Then I tried installing vue-cli version2 globally. It asked me root permission to install vue-cli globally. When I am trying to install vue template, it is again asking for root permission. Drawback of giving this root permission is, I need to give root permission for every file save, and I am not even able to create any new file(html,css or anyfile) inside the directory, since it has only read permission.
What should i do? I tried changing file permission, sudo chmod 777 filepath. But it didnot solve my problem.
Here are the pics
[I have node installed still getting this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1kj3.png)
[Here it shows, I have eaccess permission error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyfGX.png)
How to fix them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change access permissions on folder ".vue-templates/" for the active user. You can use the following command. It worked for me.

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) path_to_vue_templates_folder`